# Error X3502: ds_5_0 tessfactor missing

Tags: shader, directx-11, tessellation

I am getting the above error from my shader. 
Hull shader code snippet:

```
struct ConstantOutputType
{
    float edges[4] : SV_TessFactor;
    float inside[2] : SV_InsideTessFactor;
};

ConstantOutputType PatchConstantFunction(InputPatch<InputType, 3> inputPatch, uint patchId : SV_PrimitiveID)
{    
ConstantOutputType output;


output.edges[0] = 2;
output.edges[1] = 2;
output.edges[2] = 4;
output.edges[3] = 4;


output.inside[0] = 2;
output.inside[1] = 4;

return output;
}
```

And a snippet from my domain shader where the error is coming from:

```
struct ConstantOutputType
{
     float edges[3] : SV_TessFactor;
     float inside[2] : SV_InsideTessFactor;
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the error!

ds_5_0 is the Domain Shader profile. Compile your Hull Shader with hs_5_0.

Comment: Im sorry I don't know what you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would have got a warning about Domain Shader profile 5.0 if you were compiling a Hull Shader using hs_5_0, but you've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by changing input patch to receive 4 rather than 3.

Thanks